# Windows 8.1 Pro x64 can't create homegroup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, home-networking

Today I wanted to copy some files over homegroup to my PC from my Notebook but homegroup wasn't available so I checked my PC and saw that Network and Sharing showed no connection but it was connected and I was able to browse on the internet.

I found a Microsoft forum with a similar problem. There someone said that the `HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/NetworkList` and its subkeys permissions needs to be full access for all the users in the list except creator/owner, so I changed the permissions and after reboot the network showed up properly, but I still wasn't able to access homegroup from my notebook, so I deleted the homegroup connection on the notebook and tried to re-join and than an error message showed up stating that the HomeGroup is no longer avaiable.

Than I deleted the HomeGroup on my PC and tried to create a new but it stops with an error stating that HomeGroup can only be created on Private network, but Network and Sharing shows I'm on a private network.
So after this I made windows forget my wi-fi connection and deleted idstore.sset, than I re-connected to my wi-fi and allowed windows to find devices and other computers, but I still get the same error stating that HomeGrop can only be created on private network.

I tried running the network and homegroup trouble shooter but none of them finds an error.

What can I do resolve this issue?